# Finding best combination matlab with formula

Tags: matlab, optimization, combinations

I have a formula here:

```
E = T*(1-W)*U + X*W*F + S*W*C*D
```

Lets say `T`, `W`,`S`,`X` and `D` are all constants, while `U`, `F` and `C` are variables and `F` and `C` are related to each other.

Now my aim is to find different values of `E` based on different combinations of `U`, `F` and `C`.

For example I have values for these variables:

```
U = 2.02,  1,     3,      4
F = 6,     4,     3.03
C = 0.5,   0.4,   0.3
```

Noting that `F` and `C` are related to each other e.g. when `F=6` then `C=0.5` or if `F=4` then `C=0.4` and so on.

Can anyone help me how to execute this on matlab so that matlab will calculate the value for `E` for all possible combinations of variables.

Comment: Do you mean you first want to do something with all first values, than with all second etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a relation

F = 10*(exp(C)-1.06);

from your data. I don't know if that is consistent with your expectations. Regardless, once you choose the range of C,F, and U and the size of the steps to sample the individual variables, you can compute the phase space of your function like this:

```
%%%% modify me %%%%
T = 1;
W = 1;
S = 1;
X = 1;
D = 1;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Nstep = 10;

U = [2.02, 1, 3 , 4];
F = [6, 4, 3.03];
C = [0.5, 0.4, 0.3];

Umin = min(U);
Umax = max(U);
Cmin = min(C);
Cmax = max(C);
Fmin = min(F);
Fmax = max(F);

Ustep = (Umax-Umin)/Nstep;
Fstep = (Fmax-Fmin)/Nstep;
Cstep = (Cmax-Cmin)/Nstep;

U = [Umin:Ustep:Umax];
C = [Cmin:Cstep:Cmax];
F = [Fmin:Fstep:Fmax];
[C,F,U] = MESHGRID(C,F,U);

E = T.*(1-W).*U + X.*W.*F + S.*W.*C.*D;
```

If the remaining variables T, W, S, X, D are not scalars you'll need to adjust the size of the arrays holding them.

Comment: @JordanDavid Please remember to click on the check mark of an answer that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your question. If you just want to loop through 3 variables with known values, where two of them are correlated, you can use for example:

```
U = [2.02 1 3  4];
F = [6 4 3.03];
C = [0.5 0.4 0.3];
T = 1; W = 2; S = 3; X = 4; D = 5; %example values

for j=1:size(U,2)
    for i=1:size(F,2)
        E = T*(1-W)*U(j) + X*W*F(i) + S*W*C(i)*D; disp (E);
    end
end
```

Otherwise, we need probably a bit more details about the relation between F and C.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this, it is not very optimized but should be easy to understand.

```
U = [2.02 1 3  4];
F = [6 4 3.03];
C = [0.5 0.4 0.3];
[W, T, D, X, S] = deal(1); %Assign dummy values for now
minLength =  min(min(numel(U),numel(F)),numel(C)); %As U is not the same length as F and C here
E = zeros(minLength,1);
for k = 1:minLength
    E(k) = T*(1-W)*U(k) + X*W*F(k) + S*W*C(k)*D;
end
```

You can now find the lowest value by doing:

```
find(E == min(E))
```

Comment: if `U` is not related the answer by @user2042297 should help you.